# Store Table Row Selections Across Multiple Pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a search results table with a checkbox allowing users to select 1 or more rows - this is working fine on a single page at the moment. However I have to use pagination to limit the results to 20 rows per page, so once the user clicks the Next Page button to go to the 2nd page of search results their selections are lost.

Is there a way to keep their selections from page to page?

Here's an example of how the table appears with the script that sets a hidden form input:

```js
$(function() {


  //column checkbox select all or cancel
  $("input.select-all").click(function() {
    var checked = this.checked;
    $("input.select-item").each(function(index, item) {
      item.checked = checked;
    });
    // update the hidden input with the selected selectedProductIDs
    var items = [];
    $("input.select-item:checked:checked").each(function(index, item) {
      items[index] = item.value;
    });
    if (items.length < 1) {
      $('#selectedProductIDs').val('');
    } else {
      var values = items.join(',');
      $('#selectedProductIDs').val(values);
    }
  });

  //check selected items
  $("input.select-item").click(function() {
    var checked = this.checked;
    console.log(checked);
    checkSelected();
    // update the hidden input with the selected assetIDs
    var items = [];
    $("input.select-item:checked:checked").each(function(index, item) {
      items[index] = item.value;
    });
    if (items.length < 1) {
      $('#selectedProductIDs').val('');
    } else {
      var values = items.join(',');
      $('#selectedProductIDs').val(values);
    }

  });

  //check is all selected
  function checkSelected() {
    var all = $("input.select-all")[0];
    var total = $("input.select-item").length;
    var len = $("input.select-item:checked:checked").length;
    console.log("total:" + total);
    console.log("len:" + len);
    all.checked = len === total;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th><input type="checkbox" class="select-all checkbox" name="select-all" /></th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col">Product ID</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col">Description</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr class="" id="85799">
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36288" /></td>
      <td>12345</td>
      <td>Apples</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" id="85800">
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36289" /></td>
      <td>67890</td>
      <td>Bananas</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" id="85801">
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36290" /></td>
      <td>55441</td>
      <td>Oranges</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<form class="form-horizontal" id="processSelections" action="processSelections.php" method="post" role="form">
  <input type="hidden" name="selectedProductIDs" id="selectedProductIDs" value="">

  <div>

    <div class="text-center">
      <button type="submit" name="buttonType" value="createShipments" id="save" class="btn btn-success">Process Selections</button> &nbsp; &nbsp;
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: why the php tag? there's no php here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm using PHP on the server, wasn't sure if there is a way to do this using PHP session variables etc. The page navigation is to a PHP page as well

Comment: there would be a way to keep their results found with sessions, yes. Have you gone through the manuals on php.net yet or tutorials? I myself am not a JS guy btw.

Comment: How are you handling pagination? Because you could `echo` out the `_POST` parameter for the page number, and pipe that into jQuery.

Comment: The selections are more like adding items to cart, so, it better be stored on the server via sessions or even better, stored in DB with that users' SESSION ID. If you want to do it this way, I can provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: @user982124, you said this code works fine, check to see what happens when you select an item and deselect it afterwards. I'm trying to understand what your code does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having the AJAX script call a PHP page which updated a $_SESSION variable with the selected items so this would persist from page to page.